# Cox model data setup using coxph in R

Tags: survival, cox-model

I am trying to set up a Cox regression model in R using `coxph` in `survival` package. I have two questions:

1. In the formula `coxph(Surv(time1,time2,status))`, should status always be coded as 0 and 1? The [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) examples suggest that way, but I ask because in my dataset `status` is currently coded as 1 and 2. I am just wondering whether using 1 and 2, instead of 0 and 1, will make a difference.
2. I have weekly observations in my survival data. And weeks are represented using 4 digit numbers. For e.g., the start week for a subject is 1219 and end week is 1291. When I prepare the columns `time1` and `time2`, should `time1` always start with 0 for a subject? Or can it start with 1219 in this case?

Comment: Are your questions *only* about how to use R / how the R functions work? If so, it would probably be off topic here. Can you clarify the *statistical* aspects of your questions?

Comment: These types of questions can often be answered by creating the situation you want to test and testing in R. Enter your {1,2} variable as the status and try non-zero time1 values in coxph.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your 'status' variable should be coded as 0 and 1 as this tells R which observations are censored and which are observed.
2. If your data are left-truncated, then you should enter the first time into the 'time1' formula argument and the second time into the 'time2' formula argument. This accounts for potential bias in your sampled failure/censoring times. If your data are only right-censored, then you should take the difference between your two times and enter these differences in the 'time1' argument.